# Is kinetic energy proportional to temperature for non-gases?

Tags: energy, phase, kinetic-theory-of-gases

> If the molecules in a sample of ice at $\pu{-15 °C}$ and $\pu{1 bar}$ all have their kinetic energy doubled, then what is the final phase?

The answer is gas, but I am not sure how to get this answer.

I was wondering if the equation $\displaystyle k = \frac{3}{2}RT$ still holds in this case, even though the molecules are not a gas. It seems as though it does (it gives the right answer because $2 \times \pu{258.25 K} = \pu{516.3 K},$ which is a gas), but I am not too sure why.

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: Note that the mean kinetic energy is proportional to absolute temperature for monoatomic gases only. For other gases only in temperature region where vibration is frozen at the base level.